# What 's Big O notation on this specific code?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, big-o

I want to know Big O notation and Big Omega notation 
(worst case, best case) of this code 
It is a sorting algorithm and my guess is that it has a `O(n)` and `Omega(n)`
:

```
public static void swap(int[] A, int i,int j){
    int temp = 0;
    temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
}

public static int[] MyAlgorithm(int[] A, int n){

    boolean done = true;
    int j =0;
    while(j<=(n-2)){
        if(A[j]>A[j+1]){
            swap(A,j,j+1);
            done = false;
        }
        j = j+1;
    }
    j = n-1;

    while(j>=1){
        if(A[j]<A[j-1]){
            swap(A, j-1,j);
            done = false;
        }
        j = j-1;
    }

    if(done==false){
        MyAlgorithm(A,n);
    }

    return A;
}
```

Comment: You will never achieve O(n) for a sorting algorithm.

Comment: It's a two-way bubble sort, so it's `O(n²)` like bubble sort.

Comment: @GriffeyDog That is only true for comparison-based sorts. Other algorithms can trade increased space complexity for improved time complexity (radix sort, for example).

Comment: seems like you dont really know big O and omega notations.

Answer (score 2):

It's O(n^2) (for list `[n, n-1, ..., 1]`), Omega(n) for `[1, 2, ..., n]`.

Comment: Please could you explain =)

Comment: If the list is already sorted then you never set `done=false`, so the function `A` is called once. If it's reverse sorted then first while loop will set max element to the end, second while will set min element on the front and so, on. So it will take `n/2` `A` calls to sort reverse sorted list.